# Deallocating item in array

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, undefined-behavior, pointer-aliasing

It if have an object, lets call it `o`, and two arrays `typeo *a,*b;` if I assign `o` to both array `a` and array `b` then `delete[] b` what happens if I try to access o or o in a? For example:

```
struct name{int a;}
name *a = new name[1];
name *b = new name[1];
name o;
a[0] = o;
b[0] = o;
delete[] b;
a[0]; // what happens here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example there are no problems. `a[0]` and `b[0]` are different objects in different memory locations, and destroying one of them has no effect on the other.

The `new` is a red herring; the following code works the same way:

```
name o;
name a = o;
{
   name b = o;
}

a;
```

`name` has *value semantics*, that is, copying it by value creates a wholly distinct copy. Built-in types such as `int` all have value-semantics too.

This code would only run into problems if `o` did not have value semantics; for example, if it contains a resource handle and does not contain copy-constructor and assignment-operator code for duplicating the resource handle.

Then copying `o` would make two objects with the same handle on that resource, and if `o`'s destructor releases the resource it would leave a dangling copy.

To avoid these problems it is usually recommended to design all of your classes to have value semantics.  If the class has a handle on a resource that is not duplicatable, then the class should have its copy-constructor and assignment-operator disabled to prevent inadvertant copies. In fact, the resource handle should be held by a class designed for resource handles.

This is sometimes known as "rule of three" (or since C++11, "rule of five" or "rule of zero").

Answer (score 2):

If you just define int `a[1]` you are not allocating memory in heap, so no need to delete.

Otherwise if you create an array as follows:
 `int *a= new int[1]` , 
you have to delete as
 `delete [] a;`

By considering both above  scenarios,  you can safely access `a' after you delete b if you have allocated  memory for b and a.

Comment: I'll edit and add more precise code, this is close to what I'm looking for but not quite.